# Centering main wrapper with dynamic width

Tags: css, alignment

I have searched and searched. Fiddled and tweaked. Spent hours trying different suggestions and code ideas...

How can I have the content on my webpage, be centered horizontally with regards to the browsers view port. No matter what I do, I always end up with uneven margins and it is quite noticeable.

The closest so far is:

```css
#MyStyleName
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
}
```

However, because I am using a percentage, no matter what I do with margins/alignment it just defaults to being on the left edge of the page.

extra info:
My issue relates to the top-level, most outer page element. The very first  or  that holds the content of everything else.

Comment: please add your fiddle or plunkr here.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking, but here is a example of af centered `<div>` with a percentage with.

I also added `border-sizing: border-box` which enables you to use padding.

```css
#MyStyleName {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  display:block;
  background:red; /* Only for testing */
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="MyStyleName">
  Hi!
</div>
```

Comment: It looks much nicer, but it still doesn't work.
My issue relates to the top-level, most outer page element. The very first <div> or <table> that holds the content of everything else.

Answer (score 0):

If your `#MyStyleName` is a block element, then it should work. If not, then it's not gonna work. In such case you can add `display:block;` to the selector style.